# Cannot set focus() on an entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I try to set focus on an entry widget I receive an error,

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonPrograms/Tkinter/test_case.py", line 13, in <module>
    entSearch.focus()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'focus'
```

From searching for other occurrences of this error on Stack overflow the fix appeared to be calling the grid method on a separate line.

```py
entSearch = Entry(main, textvariable = text, width = 50, font='arial 12')
entSearch = entSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky=W)
```

rather than

```py
entSearch = Entry(main,
                  textvariable = text,
                  width = 50, 
                  font='arial 12').grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky=W)
```

Unfortunately this fix is not working for me.

```py
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
main.title("Test Case")
main.geometry('750x750')
main.configure(background='ivory3')

text = StringVar()

entSearch = Entry(main, textvariable = text, width = 50, font='arial 12')
entSearch = entSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky=W)

entSearch.focus()

main.mainloop()
```

Expected, Entry Widget would be in focus when the code is run.

But instead I receive the error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonPrograms/Tkinter/test_case.py", line 13, in <module>
    entSearch.focus()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'focus'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `focus_set()` as opposed to `focus()`. A brief [documentation](https://kite.com/python/docs/Tkinter.Tk.focus_set) on the `focus_set()` method.

EDIT:

Additionally, the line `entSearch = entSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky=W)` is also causing problems. By default, the `grid` method does not return a value (only displays a given widget). Therefore, it returns `None` - you store this value in `entSearch` which means you can't 'focus' in on a `None` object. To solve this, simply remove the assignment and display your widget as such: `entSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky=W)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried using focus_set() but am getting the same exact result.

Comment: That worked, thanks!!! BTW, I tried it with both focus() and focus_set(). Both work. What's the difference?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I see that focus is an alias for focus_set. Thanks